# Is it worth upgrading to Apache commons VFS 2.0?

Tags: apache-commons

Ive had trouble getting a definitive summary (aka release notes) of what has been fixed, changed and so on with 2.0. Has anybody tried it and what experience have they had. I have noticed many bugs with providers such as the inability to move directories (Ram). There also seems to be lots of open issues that would affect the core system rather than edge cases

Answer (score 0):

I have been running 2.0-RC1 for a while and just updated to 2.0.

There are a lot of thread local leaks which will affect you if running on a thread pooled environment. They have renamed the package to org.apache.commons.vfs2

The reason we upgraded is that they have fixed virtual file systems (they were barely usable in 1.0)